# Intellij idea DB Navigator plugin limitation.

Tags: database, postgresql, intellij-idea

I have just installed the intellij idea plugin DB Navigator to view Postgresql database and I am wondering whether I can show the values of the user-defined columns or not,plus is it possible to update/insert record by the gui tool not by writing sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that plugin to achieve what you want. Just use the basic [database integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/database_tools.html).

Open the Database view: `View > Tool Windows > Database` (or click on `Database` on the right ribbon), add your Postgres database, select your table and open the Table Editor (`F4`). Now you can [add, delete and update entries](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/table-editor.html) without writing SQL.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know, but this only happens in the ultimate version, I have the community one and there is a plugin called DB Navigator to enable the community version of having a database tool.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800?pr=phpStorm